# Is there a way to let R use data respective of another column?

Tags: r, dataframe, datatable, pairwise, categorization

I have a data set that is has colnames "Phenotype" and "Phenotype_Measurement" (total dataset named "ThermalVar"). I'm trying to run a pairwise function between two specific phenotypes' measurements, but am lost on how to tell R to look at the "Phenotype_Measurement" contingently to the "Phenotype column."

My best guess is this:

pairs(ThermalVar,Phenotype%in% = c(1Week-AcclimationSurvival_NegativeSixDegreesC_F, 1Week-Non-acclimationSurvival_NegativeSixDegreesC_F),
pch = 21,
bg = rainbow(2))

Hugely grateful for any help!

Comment: From your text I don't have a clue what your goal is, but your syntax would be correct if you do `Phenotype %in% c("1Week-AcclimationSurvival_NegativeSixDegreesC_F", "1Week-Non-acclimationSurvival_NegativeSixDegreesC_F")`, assuming those "1Week..." strings are values in the `Phenotype` column. If my guess is wrong, please clarify your goal and also add a few rows of sample data to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking to filter? The question is unclear. The following will filter conditions where `Phenotype` is equal to any of the values in the vector, where `pch` is 12, and bg is equal to the result of rainbow(2).

```
library(dplyr)

ThermalVar %>% 
  filter(Phenotype %in% c("1Week-AcclimationSurvival_NegativeSixDegreesC_F", 
                          "1Week-Non-acclimationSurvival_NegativeSixDegreesC_F"),
          pch == 21,
          bg == rainbow(2))
```